# Getting Lowest Used Price with Amazon API

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am using Django with Amazon API to receive books pricing. I NEED the Used Book Lowest Price. I keep getting the New Lowest Price showing. Below is the code my developer used. She said there is no way to get the Used Lowest Price. I have tried multiple different variations of the Offers/OfferSummary etc. Still not change. I also tried adding Response elements but no change... From what I read amazon always returns the Lowest New Price first and then the Lowested Used Price.

I am not great with coding but it looks like BeautifulSoup is just pulling the first amount that is shown. Any thoughts on how I can achieve this? Spent all day with changes and got no where getting the Used prices....

```
price_response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId=isbn, IdType="ISBN", SearchIndex="Books", 
                                   MerchantID="All", ResponseGroup="Small,OfferSummary")
try:
    desc_soup = BeautifulSoup(price_response,"html.parser")
    book_price = desc_soup.amount.get_text()
    book_price =float( book_price)/100
    book_price = decimal.Decimal(book_price)
    price_range = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the code is just finding the first amount that it can. This should work:

```
desc_soup = BeautifulSoup(price_response)
book_price = desc_soup.lowestusedprice.amount.get_text()
```

You really shouldn't be using `html.parser` either given that the API response is XML. You should do this instead:

```
desc_soup = BeautifulSoup(price_response, 'xml')
book_price = desc_soup.LowestUsedPrice.Amount.get_text()
```

(Note the capitalisation of the tree objects changes. You also need `lxml` to be installed for this to work).

Comment: 2 full days trying to get this to work. And you solved it with one post. I really appreciate it ALOT! Thank you.